# Deploying iOS app for development on multiple devices

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, app-id

I'm working on developing an application for iPhone. I recently acquired a new development device, and would like to deploy the application to this device for testing, in addition to the device I have already been using.

When I try to deploy the application, I get an error saying that:

```
No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the device "name of my device"
```

I have read the documentation on Apple's official developer portal, but it's unclear to me what I can re-use on this new device and what has to be created for it uniquely.

Can I use the same AppId? (I would hope so, since I can only have one app Id for a given Bundle ID)

I generated a new certificate request and named it something different. I also tried to add the new development device as a device allowed to use the provisioning profile I am already using in the application. Apparently, my code signing identity is still not found when trying to build on the new device. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your new device identifier to the Provisioning Profile in the Development Portal. The process should be automated if you connect the device while Xcode is open, check out the Organizer for registration progress.

Comment: @DavidDeRosa I already added the new device and added it to the provisioning profile I had already been using- but when I download and drag the provisioning portal to the device (in Organizer) it says "no valid signing identity found", Do I need to just start over by making a team provisioning profile?

Comment: You may have the certificate locally but not the signing private key, have you checked the certificate/key association in the local keychain?

Answer (score 0):

Delete old profile from xcode and download fresh copy of provisioning profile with new device identifier. Add this profile to xcode.
Go to Project -> Build settings-> Code Signing -> there select latest downloaded profile.
It will work